# How to set setAnimationInterval in cocos2d-x for android?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I am porting `cocos2d` iOS game to android game by using `cocos2d-x`.
But now, I have a problem. In original game, it used `[pDirector setAnimationInterval:1.0 / 240];`
So, I have implemented it following such this `pDirector->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 240);`
But it doesn't work correctly. Please solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the fps on android systems cannot be controlled.
Take a look at the issue on github [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/8392).